# Crear una tabla si existe la base de datos, si no crearla en otra base

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Quiero verificar si existe una base de datos BDDATOS1 , si existe creo una tabla en dicha base BDDATOS1, de lo contrario creo una tabla en la base de datos BDDATOS2.

Cuando ejecuto lo siguiente

```
   IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM master.dbo.SYSDATABASES WHERE NAME = 'BDDATOS1')

    CREATE TABLE BDDATOS1.._articulos2 ([carticulos_id] [char] (8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,  [cagrupacion_articulos_id] [char] (9) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,  [carticulos_nombre] [char] (80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL );
   else 
    CREATE TABLE BDDATOS2.._articulos2 ([carticulos_id] [char] (8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,  [cagrupacion_articulos_id] [char] (9) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,  [carticulos_nombre] [char] (80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL );
end
```

me da un error pre ejecucion diciendo que BDDATOS1 no existe, lo cual es verdad, pero se supone que deberia pasar a la sentencia del ELSE y crear la tabla en la base de datos BDDATOS2.

Este error solo me sale con create, con UPDATE, SELECT y DROP no me da error.

Answer (score 1):

No, no puedes hacerlo del modo que lo planteas básicamente por que el motor evalúa completamente el Script, y efectivamente la instrucción `CREATE TABLE BDDATOS1.._articulos2` es inválida si no existe `BDDATOS1`.

Un forma de resolverlo es hacer que no se evalúe la sentencia de creación que da el error:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(2000)

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM master.dbo.SYSDATABASES WHERE NAME = 'BDDATOS1')
BEGIN

    SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE BDDATOS1.._articulos2 ([carticulos_id] [char] (8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,  [cagrupacion_articulos_id] [char] (9) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,  [carticulos_nombre] [char] (80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL );'

END ELSE BEGIN

    SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE BDDATOS2.._articulos2 ([carticulos_id] [char] (8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,  [cagrupacion_articulos_id] [char] (9) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,  [carticulos_nombre] [char] (80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL );'

END

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Como ves, armamos una sentencia `@SQL` en función de la existencia de una base de datos y la ejecutamos directamente mediante: `EXEC sp_executesql @SQL`, esto evita la evaluación del Script que nos daba el error, pero si, se evalúa `@SQL` con el cual no tendremos problemas por que ya esta construido de acuerdo a la base de datos que corresponda.

Nota: El uso de `sp_executesql` debiéramos limitarlo a situaciones específicas y controladas ya que puede ser una fuente de problemas por:
1) Inyecciones de código malicioso 2) Problemas de rendimiento por ausencias de las optimizaciones que realiza el motor.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes comprobar directamente en el `if` la query de esa manera. Deberías almacenar el resultado y hacer la comparación con él.

Creo que algo así te serviría:

```
Define @existe int
set @existe = 0
SELECT @exist= count(*) FROM master.dbo.SYSDATABASES WHERE NAME = 'BDDATOS1'
IF @exist > 0

CREATE TABLE BDDATOS1.._articulos2 ([carticulos_id] [char] (8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,  [cagrupacion_articulos_id] [char] (9) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,  [carticulos_nombre] [char] (80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL );
else 
CREATE TABLE BDDATOS2.._articulos2 ([carticulos_id] [char] (8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,  [cagrupacion_articulos_id] [char] (9) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,  [carticulos_nombre] [char] (80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL );
end
```